# Set dates in range dependent on first date of range

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

Let's say I have a horizontal range of cells in google sheets - format: date. I go to the first two cells and set the first two days of a month, grab the blue dot and drag it all over to the right so it fills the columns with all dates of the month consecutively.

However, if I want to change the month I would have to repeat the process. How do I set this up so that when I double click the first cell, open the date picker and set it to a different month, all the other cell dates change accordingly to the new month INCLUSIVE the correct amount of columns to be filled according to the number of dates of the month. So when I set from Jan to Feb I don't have three columns left over from Jan.

Wondering if there is a solution without a script - I feel there is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(TO_DATE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("A"&DATE(YEAR(A1), MONTH(A1), DAY(A1)+1)):
 INDIRECT("B"&EOMONTH(A1, 0))))))
```

[image]

Comment: fantastic - direct hit ... had to wrap my head quite a bit around it to understand that one ... adjusted it a bit to my situation making it all relative to one single named range representing the first day of the month - cell:

=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(TO_DATE(ROW(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(FirstDayOfMonth),4),ROW(FirstDayOfMonth),"")&DATE(YEAR(FirstDayOfMonth), MONTH(FirstDayOfMonth), DAY(FirstDayOfMonth)+1)):INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(FirstDayOfMonth)+1,4),ROW(FirstDayOfMonth),"")&EOMONTH(FirstDayOfMonth, 0))))))

Answer (score 1):

- put your date in **A1**
- paste this in **B1** and drag to the right **`=$A$1+COLUMN()-1`**

[image: 0]

[image: 00]

Comment: Works, in my case I used: =FirstDayOfMonth+COLUMN()-COLUMN(FirstDayOfMonth)

However, does not solve the different month lenghtes problem ...

Answer (score 1):

I use this nice and clean formula :

```
=SEQUENCE(1,500,DATEVALUE("01/12/2021 23:00:00"))
```